# How do I shift my weight on a motorcycle?

Tags: ios, grand-theft-auto-vice-city

Is it possible to shift your weight in order to increase your speed on a motorcycle while playing Vice City on iOS? I'm having a hard time making some of the unique jumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your controls to Analog Stick from two buttons.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I should have read the control options more carefully.